# FusedLocationProviderClient.getCurrentLocation() никогда не выполняется

Tags: android

Получаю последние координаты с помощью `getLastLocation()`, с этим проблем никаких нет. В случае, если последних координат нет, то пытаюсь получить текущие с помощью `getCurrentLocation()`, но в результате ничего не происходит - никакой из Listener`ов(onComplete/failure/...) не вызывается.

```
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity)
val cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource()
fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(
                        LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER,
                        cancellationTokenSource.token
                    ).addOnCompleteListener { location: Task<Location> ->
                        println("location $location")
                    }
```

Comment: У вас включен GPS? Если выключен листенер не будет работать.

Comment: Это было бы слишком просто. Проблема в приоритете.